# For Each group show the record with the latest timestamp. If multiple records within a group have same timestamp, select row having non null value

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, lambda, group-by

I have the following Pandas DataFrame.

| Id | Name | Timestamp | Val 1 | Val 2 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | A | 2017-04-13 14:09:00 | 2.3 | None |
| 1 | A | 2017-04-13 14:09:00 | 2.3 | 4.3 |
| 1 | A | 2017-04-11 13:09:00 | 2.1 | 3.3 |
| 1 | B | 2017-06-13 11:09:00 | None | None |
| 1 | B | 2017-06-13 11:09:00 | 3.3 | 1.3 |
| 2 | A | 2018-08-10 11:08:00 | 4.3 | None |
| 2 | A | 2017-04-13 14:29:00 | 4.3 | 4.3 |
| 3 | B | 2019-04-11 13:09:00 | None | None |
| 3 | B | 2017-06-13 11:09:00 | 1.2 | 2.1 |
| 4 | B | 2017-05-13 11:09:00 | 1.5 | 2.7 |

For Each Id and Name I want to find the record with the latest timestamp which has non null values.
The expected output is

| Id | Name | Timestamp | Val 1 | Val 2 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | A | 2017-04-13 14:29:00 | 2.3 | 4.3 |
| 1 | B | 2017-06-13 11:09:00 | 3.3 | 1.3 |
| 2 | A | 2017-04-13 14:29:00 | 4.3 | 4.3 |
| 3 | B | 2017-06-13 11:09:00 | 1.2 | 2.1 |
| 4 | B | 2017-05-13 11:09:00 | 1.5 | 2.7 |

How can I achieve this?

I am trying to Group by Id and Name and taking the max but it returns the row with null values.

`df.groupby(['Id','Name']).max()`

Comment: Please post your current code.

Answer (score 2):

Assuming your `None` are real `NaN`, you can use [`dropna`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.dropna.html) then [`groupby.idxmax`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.core.groupby.DataFrameGroupBy.idxmax.html):

```
df['Timestamp'] = pd.to_datetime(df['Timestamp'])

keep = (df.dropna(subset=['Val 1', 'Val 2'])
          .groupby(['Id', 'Name'])['Timestamp'].idxmax()
        )

out = df.loc[keep]
```

Output:

```
   Id Name           Timestamp Val 1 Val 2
1   1    A 2017-04-13 14:09:00   2.3   4.3
4   1    B 2017-06-13 11:09:00   3.3   1.3
6   2    A 2017-04-13 14:29:00   4.3   4.3
8   3    B 2017-06-13 11:09:00   1.2   2.1
9   4    B 2017-05-13 11:09:00   1.5   2.7
```